# How to access the quasar spectrum from the FITS file in SDSS DR16 catalog

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I am trying to access the SDSS catalog through the FITS file I downloaded [here](https://www.sdss4.org/dr17/algorithms/qso_catalog/), I am looking at the  DR16Q_v4.fits file.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find where the actual spectrum data is located even though I can find all the information listed in the [data models](https://data.sdss.org/datamodel/files/BOSS_QSO/DR16Q/), none of the table listed contain an array with a length long enough to be the flux array or the wavelength array.

I tried navigating the file on my own :

```
from astropy.io import fits

file = fits.open("C:\\Users\\Lord Duck\\Downloads\\DR16Q_v4.fits")

file.info()

h1=file[1].header
print(repr(h1))
```

wields the expected description given in the previous data models :

```
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU       4   ()      
  1  CATALOG       1 BinTableHDU    375   750414R x 183C   [18A, D, D, J, J, I, 6A, 6A, I, D, I, D, I, I, I, K, D, I, I, D, I, D, I, D, D, I, D, 12A, D, J, 19A, D, K, D, D, K, D, D, K, D, D, K, D, D, K, D, D, K, D, D, K, D, E, 5D, 5D, 5D, E, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, K, K, K, K, K, K, J, J, J, 74J, 74J, 74I, 74I, B, J, 3A, J, J, J, D, D, D, D, 14A, J, D, 5E, 5D, 5E, 5D, 5E, D, D, I, D, D, D, D, I, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, I, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, I, I, D, D, D, D, D, D, J, D, D, D, J, D, D, D, J, D, 21A, D, D, E, E, D, K, D, D, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, D, I, 28A, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D]   
XTENSION= 'BINTABLE'           / binary table extension                         
BITPIX  =                    8 / array data type                                
NAXIS   =                    2 / number of array dimensions                     
NAXIS1  =                 2290 / length of dimension 1                          
NAXIS2  =               750414 / length of dimension 2                          
PCOUNT  =                    0 / number of group parameters                     
GCOUNT  =                    1 / number of groups                               
TFIELDS =                  183 / number of table fields                         
TTYPE1  = 'SDSS_NAME'                                                           
TFORM1  = '18A     '                                                            
TTYPE2  = 'RA      '                                                            
TFORM2  = 'D       '                                                            
TTYPE3  = 'DEC     '                 
....
```

Going further I tried extracting the data :

```
data=file[1].data
print(len(data))
```

Which wields :

```
750414
```

So I assume that data is an *array* of length 750414 which represent all the different quasar from the SDSS catalog and going one step further :`print(len(data[0]))` wields `183` corresponding to the 183 tables with all the characteristic of each quasar.

But where is the spectrum ?

Comment: The basic catalogue may well be just a list of the objects and their parameters. The spectral data look to me like they are in the 2.4GB ad 1.7GB files on the site you linked to.

Comment: The file I am looking at, the _DR16Q_v4.fits_ is the 1.7Gb, and I have tried with the 2.4Gb file aswell to no avail. It's just that the header have been named 'CATALOG' as described in the [data models V4](https://data.sdss.org/datamodel/files/BOSS_QSO/DR16Q/DR16Q_v4.html) and [data models V3](https://data.sdss.org/datamodel/files/BOSS_QSO/DR16Q/DR16Q_Superset_v3.html)

Comment: I don't think there are spectra in that file: it's just a catalogue of 750414 quasars with relevant parameters, such as ra & dec, redshift, (integrated) fluxes etc. To obtain the spectrum of a selected source, you'll have to query the SDSS data (there are numerous way to do that) and download the spectra individually.